# Circular slider for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

Out of the box, Watch Kit has a slider which allows you to tap minus or plus. However, I would like a slider that allows you to slide your finger to specify the value of the slider. How can something like this be done?

Below is a sample of the kind of circular slider I'm trying to accomplish (notice how to change the radio station and how to change the volume):
https://dribbble.com/shots/1744765-Radio-Watch-Animation-Freebie

Comment: This isn't possible yet—the current WatchKit SDK is limited to only the built-in controls. When a full SDK is released later this year something like that might be possible.